# Constants for the Domain and Range of a Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We're currently learning about this in high school, and I was looking ahead in the textbook. Since we just had finals and we're on break, I wasn't able to ask anyone about this problem.
It would be great if you could help me with the following problem.

*f*(*x*) is a function with domain [0; 4) and range (-1; 2]. If *g*(*x*) = *a*  *f*(*bx* + *c*) + *d*, for some constants *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d*, and *g*(*x*) has domain (1; 2] and range (3; 7], find the values of *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d*.

So far, I know that b and c affect the domain of the function, while a and d affect the range.

Once again, I am not looking for a complete answer to this problem, but a few hints or an explanation of the process would definitely help. I appreciate the time you took to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints, assuming that the ranges of these functions are totally filled out.

1. No matter what number $y$ we might plug in to $f$, we know that $$-1 < f(y) \leqslant 2.$$
   Since the range of $g$ is the set $(3, 7]$, 
   we know that $$3 < a f(y) + c \leqslant 7.$$
   Now do a bit of rearranging:
   $$3 - c < a f(y) \leqslant 7 - c.$$
   Now, $a$ cannot be zero because the range of $g$ is not just the set $\{0\}$.
   Moreover, $a$ cannot be negative because multiplying an inequality $x < y \leqslant z$ by a negative number $n$ reverses the inequalities: $nx > ny \geqslant nz$, or, written the other way, $nz \leqslant ny < nx$, which has the opposite "shape" compared to $x < y \leqslant z$. 
   So $a$ must be positive, and we can divide by it:
   $$\frac{3 - c}{a} < f(y) \leqslant \frac{7 - c}{a}.$$
   See a resemblance?
2. If $x$ is in the domain of $g$, then we know that $$1 < x \leqslant 2.$$
   In order to be permitted to plug $bx + c$ into $f$, the number $bx + c$ must be in the domain of $f$, so we must have 
   $$0 \leqslant bx + c < 4.$$
   Doing some rearranging similar to the above, 
   $$-c \leqslant bx < 4-c.$$
   The "shape" of this inequality is opposite the shape of the inequality $1 < x \leqslant 2$. I think you can go from here!

Comment: Case analysis is not necessary for the solution of this problem.